# Cannot get model value in Controller method in Angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am developing an app in Angular js

javascript:

```
  $scope.spentAmount = function() {   
    angular.forEach($scope.expenses, function(expense) {
    if(expense.done){
    console.log($scope.spentamount);
    }     
    }); 
    //return amount;    
  };
```

HTML:

```
<label for="spentby">Spent by</label>
         <ul class="unstyled">
      <li ng-repeat="expense in expenses">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="expense.done">
        <span>{{expense.text}}</span>

        <input type="text"  ng-show="expense.done" ng-model="spentamount"  size="30"
             placeholder="Enter the amount">
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form ng-submit="addExpense()">
      <input type="text" ng-model="expenseText"  size="30"
             placeholder="Enter the names">
      <input class="btn-primary" type="submit" value="Add">
    </form>
<label for="amountspent">Amount spent(Rs)</label>
 <span>{{spentAmount()}}</span><br>
```

but `console.log($scope.spentamount)` returns undefined.

But the method gets called
Please Advice

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the 'undefined' is in the async behaviour. Your code is going through the collection of expenses sooner then it is loaded. Check the [$watch(watchExpression, listener, objectEquality)](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope)

a draft how to observe changing colleciton `expenses`

```
// a new variable containing total
$scope.total = 0;

$scope.$watch('expenses', function (exps) {
    angular.forEach(exps, function (exp) {
        if(exp.done){
           // here should/must be your calculation
            $scope.total + exp.Amount;
        }
    });
});
```

now we can adjust the template and consume the up-to-date result

```
<!--<span>{{spentAmount()}}</span><br>-->
<span>{{total}}</span><br>
```

Also think about introducing something like $scope.myModel = { expenses : [], total : 0 }... Because:

> if you use ng-model there has to be a dot somewhere. If you don't have a dot, you're doing it wrong...

Answer (score 0):

While binding inside the ng-repeat you need to use $parent to use parent scope, like-

```
  <li ng-repeat="expense in expenses">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="expense.done">
    <span>{{expense.text}}</span>

    <input type="text"  ng-show="expense.done" ng-model="$parent.spentamount"  size="30"
         placeholder="Enter the amount" />
  </li>
```

Comment: Thanks I tried the above solution.When I tried to enter amount for various entries,the entry gets displayed in other text boxes of respective entries