# How to retrieve the ng-model value to a controller in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller

I have a simple view with an input text field in which the user enter his name and a controller must retrieve that value an assign to `employeeDescription` variable. The problem is that the ng-model value (from the input) doesn't come to the controller, I just tried using $watch like Radim Köhler explains [Cannot get model value in controller method in angular js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20851850/cannot-get-model-value-in-controller-method-in-angular-js) but doesn't work. I just think it must be simple.

Also a just try by retrieving the `name` variable (ng-model) from the $scope, like `$scope.employeeDescription = $scope.name;` but doesn't retrieve value and the Google chrome console doesn't give me any output about that. Any solution?

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body ng-app='angularApp'>
    <div ng-controller='nameController'>
        <div>
            Name <input type="text" ng-model='name' />
        </div>

        Welcome {{employeeDescription}}
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
(function(angular) {
    var myAppModule = angular.module('angularApp', []);

    myAppModule.controller('nameController', function($scope) {
        $scope.employeeDescription = name;
    });

})(window.angular);
```

Comment: you can't 2 way bind primitives. which is why you should always have a dot in `ng-model` which means you are using an object to bind to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should fail, cause the 'name' variable in the controller is never defined. You have two variables defined in your code: $scope.employeeDescription and $scope.name (defined in the ng-model of the input). Note that '$scope.name' is being defined, not 'name'.

My suggestion is to leave only one variable:

```
<div>
    Name <input type="text" ng-model='employeeDescription' />
</div>

myAppModule.controller('nameController', function($scope) {
    $scope.$watch('employeeDescription', function() {
        console.log($scope.employeeDescription);
    });
});
```

Comment: But what about if I want to build a string message with using that variable inside the controller, how can I retrieve that value?

Comment: updated the answer with a watcher to check the employeeDescription and do something with it, in this case, log it ;) I'd suggest add an ng-blur to the input and process your string in a function called there, so you edit the string once the user has finnished editing ;)